# Airport Data - How do i scrape data and maintain the heirarchy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape information from https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating

I want to make a csv/excel which has the following columns
- category,
- subcategory
- rating

category    subcategory rating
Ground Transportation   Public Transport options    3.5
Ground Transportation   Distance to public transport    4
Ground Transportation   Airport taxi service    4.5
Ground Transportation   Car Rental  4.5
Security Screening  Screening guide signage 4
Security Screening  Waiting times   4
Security Screening  Service efficiency  4
Security Screening  Staff attitude and courtesy 4
Security Screening  Staff language skills   4
Security Screening  FastTrack security  5

But i get each column as a single list, with no hierarchical integrity

category    subCategory starRating
Ground Transportation,Security Screening,Immigration Service,Wayfinding & Signage,Arrival,Departure,Transfer,Terminal Comfort,Terminal Facilities,Shopping Facilities,Food & Beverage

Public Transport options,Distance to public transport,Airport taxi service,Car Rental,Screening guide signage,Waiting times,Service efficiency,Staff attitude and courtesy,Staff language skills,FastTrack security,

,,

Have tried googling and reading documentation on scrapy but am lost

```
import scrapy


class HiaskytraxratingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'HIASkytraxRatings'
    allowed_domains = ['skytraxratings.com']
    start_urls = ['https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating']

    def parse(self, response):

        print("processing:"+response.url)
        #Extract using css selectors
        #None

        #Extract using xpath
        category = response.xpath("//div[@class='ratingstable']/h4[@class='ratingstable__title fontsize-1']/text()").extract()
        subCategory = response.xpath("//div[@class='ratingstable']/div[@class='ratingstable__ratings']/div[@class='rating']/span[@class='rating__title']/text()").extract() 
        starRating = response.xpath("//div[@class='ratingstable']/div[@class='ratingstable__ratings']/div[@class='rating']/span[@class='rating__stars']").extract()



        #yield or give the scraped info to scrappy
        yield {'page':response.url,'category': category,'subCategory':subCategory,'starRating':starRating}
        pass
```

I expected:
category    subcategory rating
Ground Transportation   Public Transport options    3.5
Ground Transportation   Distance to public transport    4
Ground Transportation   Airport taxi service    4.5
Ground Transportation   Car Rental  4.5
Security Screening  Screening guide signage 4
Security Screening  Waiting times   4
Security Screening  Service efficiency  4
Security Screening  Staff attitude and courtesy 4
Security Screening  Staff language skills   4
Security Screening  FastTrack security  5

Can anyone help this scrapy noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting all the required fields at once. Try looping through each division and parsing the results.

Here is an example for you to understand. How to loop through division and use relative xpath.

```
def parse(self, response):
    print("processing:" + response.url)
    # Extract using css selectors
    # None

    # Extract using xpath
    categoryBox = ratingbox = response.xpath('//*[@class="ratingstable"]')
    for box in categoryBox:
        category = box.xpath('./h4/text()').get(default='')
        ratingBox = box.xpath('.//*[@class="rating"]')
        for rating in ratingBox:
            star_rating = len(rating.xpath('.//*[@class="fa fa-star"]').getall())
            sub_category = rating.xpath('.//*[@class="rating__title"]/text()').get(default='')
            yield {'page': response.url, 'category': category, 'subCategory': sub_category, 'starRating': star_rating}

    # category = response.xpath(
    #     "//div[@class='ratingstable']/h4[@class='ratingstable__title fontsize-1']/text()").extract()
    # subCategory = response.xpath(
    #     "//div[@class='ratingstable']/div[@class='ratingstable__ratings']/div[@class='rating']/span[@class='rating__title']/text()").extract()
    # starRating = response.xpath(
    #     "//div[@class='ratingstable']/div[@class='ratingstable__ratings']/div[@class='rating']/span[@class='rating__stars']").extract()

    # yield or give the scraped info to scrappy
```

OUTPUT

```
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Ground Transportation', 'subCategory': 'Public Transport options', 'starRating': 3}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Ground Transportation', 'subCategory': 'Distance to public transport', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Ground Transportation', 'subCategory': 'Airport taxi service', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Ground Transportation', 'subCategory': 'Car Rental', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Security Screening', 'subCategory': 'Screening guide signage', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Security Screening', 'subCategory': 'Waiting times', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Security Screening', 'subCategory': 'Service efficiency', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Security Screening', 'subCategory': 'Staff attitude and courtesy', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Security Screening', 'subCategory': 'Staff language skills', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Security Screening', 'subCategory': 'FastTrack security', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Immigration Service', 'subCategory': 'Waiting times - arrivals', 'starRating': 3}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Immigration Service', 'subCategory': 'Waiting times - departures', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Immigration Service', 'subCategory': 'Staff attitude and courtesy', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Immigration Service', 'subCategory': 'Staff language skills', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Immigration Service', 'subCategory': 'FastTrack immigration', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Wayfinding & Signage', 'subCategory': 'Ease of wayfinding - arrivals', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Wayfinding & Signage', 'subCategory': 'Ease of wayfinding - transfer', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Wayfinding & Signage', 'subCategory': 'Ease of wayfinding - departures', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Wayfinding & Signage', 'subCategory': 'Clarity of signs & symbols', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Wayfinding & Signage', 'subCategory': 'Signage language choices', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Wayfinding & Signage', 'subCategory': 'FIDS : positioning in terminal', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Wayfinding & Signage', 'subCategory': 'FIDS : clarity of display', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Wayfinding & Signage', 'subCategory': 'Terminal maps', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Wayfinding & Signage', 'subCategory': 'Airport App navigation', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Wayfinding & Signage', 'subCategory': 'Airport "help" staff', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Wayfinding & Signage', 'subCategory': 'Info Kiosks', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Wayfinding & Signage', 'subCategory': 'Info / Help counter service', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Arrival', 'subCategory': 'Walking distances', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Arrival', 'subCategory': 'Availability of toilets', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Arrival', 'subCategory': 'Baggage hall facilities', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Arrival', 'subCategory': 'Baggage delivery times', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Arrival', 'subCategory': 'Baggage carts', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Arrival', 'subCategory': 'Meet and greet facilities', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Departure', 'subCategory': 'Signage to check-in', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Departure', 'subCategory': 'Congestion around check-in', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Departure', 'subCategory': 'Queuing systems', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Departure', 'subCategory': 'Seating near check-in', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Departure', 'subCategory': 'Premium check-in facility', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Departure', 'subCategory': 'Signage to security / departures', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Transfer', 'subCategory': 'Walking distances', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Transfer', 'subCategory': 'Signage to transfer areas', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Transfer', 'subCategory': 'Transfer security screening', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Transfer', 'subCategory': 'Transfer waiting area', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Transfer', 'subCategory': 'Rest area for transfer customers', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Transfer', 'subCategory': 'Ease of transfer process', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Comfort', 'subCategory': 'Congestion around terminal', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Comfort', 'subCategory': 'Air temperature', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Comfort', 'subCategory': 'Décor and condition', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Comfort', 'subCategory': 'Seat availability', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Comfort', 'subCategory': 'Seat types and comfort', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Comfort', 'subCategory': 'Access to power / charging points', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Comfort', 'subCategory': 'Cleanliness of seats', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Comfort', 'subCategory': 'Cleanliness of washrooms', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Comfort', 'subCategory': 'Cleanliness of public areas', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Comfort', 'subCategory': 'PRM washrooms', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Comfort', 'subCategory': 'Baby changing rooms', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': "Clarity of airport PA's", 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': 'PA language translations', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': 'ATM availability', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': 'WiFi : ease of log-in', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': 'WiFi : free time allowance', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Internet kiosk facilities', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Childrens Play area', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Shower facilities', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Quiet / relaxation areas', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Dayroom facility', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Terminal hotel', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Other leisure facilities', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Terminal Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Vending machines', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Shopping Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Selection of shops : landside', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Shopping Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Selection of shops : airside', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Shopping Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Choice of mid-price shops', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Shopping Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Choice of luxury brands', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Shopping Facilities', 'subCategory': 'Staff service in shops', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Food & Beverage', 'subCategory': 'Food and beverage choice : landside', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Food & Beverage', 'subCategory': 'Fast food choice : landside', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Food & Beverage', 'subCategory': 'International brands : landside', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Food & Beverage', 'subCategory': 'Food and beverage choice : airside', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Food & Beverage', 'subCategory': 'Fast food options : airside', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Food & Beverage', 'subCategory': 'International brands : airside', 'starRating': 5}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Food & Beverage', 'subCategory': 'Food and beverage : cleanliness', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Food & Beverage', 'subCategory': 'Food and beverage : prices', 'starRating': 4}
{'page': 'https://skytraxratings.com/airports/hamad-international-airport-rating', 'category': 'Food & Beverage', 'subCategory': 'Food and beverage : staff service', 'starRating': 4}
```

I haven't counted the half stars. Simply read the numbers of half stars and divide the count by 2 and add to the star_rating.

Comment: Thank you Amit, you are a star!

Comment: Sure. I would highly recommend you to go through the documentation after you do a few projects. Then you will discover soo many efficient ways to do the things that you were struggling in your past projects.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop through the ratingstable like this:

```
ratingtables_xpath = response.xpath('//div[@class="ratingstable"]')
for ratingtable_xpath in ratingtables_xpath:
  category = ratingtable_xpath.xpath(".//h4[@class='ratingstable__title fontsize-1']/text()").extract()
  subCategory = ratingtable_xpath.xpath(".//div[@class='ratingstable__ratings']/div[@class='rating']/span[@class='rating__title']/text()").extract() 
  starRating = ratingtable_xpath.xpath(".//div[@class='ratingstable__ratings']/div[@class='rating']/span[@class='rating__stars']").extract()
  yield {'page':response.url,'category': category,'subCategory':subCategory,'starRating':starRating}
```